# Unable to remove completely the vertical paddings inside <div> when using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, padding, spacing

i am trying to remove all paddings (top + bottom) for a text inside a  block using Bootstrap 5.

when using html without Bootstrap, setting `padding: 0px` does exactly what i expect:

`<div style="padding: 0px; background-color: gray;">no bootstrap</div>` // works!

however, the moment i use Bootstrap, the padding is never 0, even after setting class `my-0`. there is always extra padding that seems to be added regardless.

`<div class="my-0 bg-info">using bootstrap my-0</div>` // doesn't work

using style to override the padding to 0 also doesn't work when the Bootstrap css is included.

`<div class="my-0 bg-info" style="padding: 0px !important;">using bootstrap my-0</div>` // doesn't work

is there a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Add the class = “p-0”. A bootstrap class that set padding to 0. For top and bottom use “py-0” and for left and right “py-0”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="p-0 m-0 bg-info">Will remove all Paddings and margins (no extra space inside and outside div)</div>
```

```
<div class="p-0 bg-info">Will remove all Paddings (no extra space inside div)</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i figured out that there is a style property `line-height` that i should use to achieve this! setting it to 1 or 1.25 works exactly as i wanted. the default with bootstrap is 1.5, hence the additional unintended padding.

Comment: also, for reference, the bootstrap className to use is `lh-1` or `lh-sm` that will achieve a very similar result.